# Firebase updateDoc function not working [Web v9 (modular)]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

from what I understand I'm doing the exact replica of Firestore's sample but I get the error:

> 'Argument type {isDismissed: boolean} is not assignable to parameter type UpdateData<{isDismissed: boolean}> '

when I use updateDoc in example below, it doesn't update the database when run. I'm using web version 9.

```
const dismissPatientAlert = (alertId) => {
    alert(alertId)
    const docRef = doc(db, 'Alerts', alertId);
    updateDoc(docRef, {isDismissed: true})
    return 'dismissed alert';
};
```

my samples source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data
Any insight will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you share your complete code so we can see where you are updating updateDoc from? Also what is your Firebase SDK version ?

Comment: Is this a TypeScript error or a runtime JS error?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use setDoc instead  ?

```
    const dismissPatientAlert = (alertId) => {
    alert(alertId)
    const docRef = doc(db, 'Alerts', alertId);
    setDoc(docRef, {isDismissed: true},{merge:true})
    return 'dismissed alert';
};
```